# When do I have to free?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

Let's say I have the following structures:

```
typedef struct first {
  int a;
  int b;
  char *c;
} *first_t;

typedef struct second {
  char *a;
  first_t b;
} *second_t;
```

The user does something like this:

```
first_t first = first_new();
second_t second = second_new();
second->b = first;
```

Where `first_new` and `second_new` allocate memory.

I want to write a `free` function for the `second_t` structure. 
I think I would have to let the user the responsability to free his `first_t` structure. Is it correct ? or do I have to write something like:

```
void second_free(second_t second) {
  free(second->a);
  first_free(second->b);
  free(second);
}
```

Comment: It's kind of weird when `first_t` is a pointer to `first`. Also, `new_first` makes more sense than `first_new`.

Comment: @FrEEzE: Agree with the pointer thing.  But I disagree with `new_first`.  If you have a load of `first_XX` functions (e.g. `first_do_this`, `first_do_that`, `first_free`), then `first_new` fits that pattern.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - Yeah, when he is doing it like that, then it would be reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  What are the semantics of your code?

If the semantics of `second->b = first` are that you are *transferring ownership*, then `second_free` should indeed call `first_free`.  (Although in this case, it may be appropriate to have a `second_create_first` function, to keep things encapsulated.)

If you are not transferring ownership, then calling `first_free` should be the responsibility of the client code.

Whatever semantics you choose, you should make things very clear in your documentation.

Comment: It makes sense but how would the user be aware of such semantics rules ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the user allocated `first`, the user should free it.

Comment: Did the user allocated `first`?

Comment: @FrEEzE Yes, it says in the question that the user calls `first_new()` to allocate `first`

Comment: Morre - Didn't see that. If the user did allocate `first` he should `free` it. Anything different wouldn't make much sense (since we don't have `smart pointers` here).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on wheter your `second_new` function does allocate memory for his member `b` or not. Allocation / deallocation should be symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Go for which ever approch you feel is more flexible.

If you think that the user has allocated the memory and user has to free.then let him do it in his own way.

If you think that you want to make a user's life easy then write a suitable free function  and let him call it if he thinks he should call it.

The question also seems to be vague here since untill the whole requirement is presented the question cant be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the approach of:

> Whoever did the allocation, is responsible for deallocation.